# Blocking the review count on all Stack Exchange websites using Adblock Plus

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

I use the Google Chrome extension [Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb?hl=en-US) to remove the review count on all Stack Exchange websites. E.g., on https://ai.stackexchange.com/ :

[image]

The element is `ai.stackexchange.com##.edit-count.unread-count`

As a result, I added the filter in Adblock Plus: `*.stackexchange.com##.edit-count.unread-count`. It removes the review count on most Stack Exchange websites but not on https://ai.stackexchange.com/. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The domain part of  `*.stackexchange.com##.edit-count.unread-count` is invalid. Writing it as `stackexchange.com##.edit-count.unread-count` will make it work on "stackexchange.com" as well as on any of its subdomains.

Sources:

- [adblockplus.org/filters](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters#elemhide_domains)
- [Filter list specification](https://github.com/ThomasGreiner/abp-spec/blob/master/filterlist.md) (created by me)